# Custom Group By postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL. I have a table called `foo`.Its content are:

```
city|number
'oo'|12
'ss'|11
'ss'|23
'oo'|11
'pp'|21
```

If I run a query like `select count(city) from foo group by city having number<21` I will get

```
city|number
'oo'|2
'ss'|2
```

but I want the result to consider all the possible cases of `city` like this:

```
city|number
'oo'|2
'ss'|2
'pp'|0
```

How should the query look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "consider all the possible cases"? 21 is not `<` 21, which is why `pp` won't show up.

Comment: yeah but the requirement is it should consider the pp as well.

Comment: Then why not just use `HAVING number <= 21`?

Comment: yeah i know..but my requirement is as group by generate column values according to condition but i want the tables like second where it should consider the all the cases. I need know what should be query to generate the second one.

Comment: Shouldn't the result have only 1 "ss"? Like `'ss'|1`?? Not to mention there is no ID in your table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is could be solved with a left join:

```
select f1.city, count(f2.number) as total from foo as f1
left join foo as f2
on f1.cityId = f2.cityId and f1.number < 21
group by f1.city
```

Here is a working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/383a8/1)

PS: Your example is wrong because ss should have a value of 1, not 2:

```
YOUR EXAMPLE         WHAT I THINK YOU REALLY WANT
city|number                   city|number
'oo'|2                        'oo'|2
'ss'|2                        'ss'|1
'pp'|0                        'pp'|0
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT city, count(NULLIF(number < 21, false)) FROM cities GROUP BY city
```

should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Think I misread the question first time, but try this:

```
select f1.city,count(*) from foo f1
where f1.city in (select f2.city from foo f2 where f2.number < 21)
group by f1.city
union 
select f3.city,0 from foo f3
where not exists (select * from foo f4 where f3.city=f4.city and f4.number < 21)
group by f3.city
```

The union splits the query so that the first half will identify which cities have an entry <21, and then count the number of occurrences of those cities.

The second half identifies cities which do not have an entry <21, and then counts them.